# Scaling of general differential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a self focusing problem that works with the following (cylindrically symmetric) eqn
$$\nabla^2_T \phi+i2k\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\phi=-2k^2n|\phi|^2\phi$$

We want to rescale so that
$$\psi(\rho,z)=A\phi(B\rho,Cz)$$
And the part I am having issues with is convincing myself that the total power ($\int |\phi|^2dA)$can be constant for certain A,B.  To figure out what the relationship must be, I do the following
$$2\pi\int|\psi|^2\rho d\rho=A^22\pi\int|\phi(B\rho,Cz)|^2\rho d\rho=2\pi\int|\phi(\rho,z)|^2\rho d\rho$$
So my question is: when rescaling from $\rho\rightarrow B\rho$ (and also with the $z\rightarrow Cz$), does that replacement occur in the integral so that the condition is that $A^2B^2=1$ or does the $\rho$ stay the same and I just get that $A^2=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $x = B\rho$ and $y = Cz$, so that

$$
2\pi \int {\rm d}\rho\;\rho |\psi(\rho,z)|^2 = 2\pi B^{-2}\int {\rm d}x\;x |\psi(x/B,y/C)| = 2\pi B^{-2} A^2\int {\rm d}x\;x |\phi(x,y)|^2
$$

The power $\int {\rm d}^2S\;|\psi|^2$ is the same in both coordinates only if $B^{-2}A^2=1$

Comment: Wait.  If x=Bp then pdp = xdx/b^2, so then the B^2 should be in the denominator, no?

Comment: @yankeefan11 You re right, just fixed it in my answer